# How do I iterate/loop an API request that has a JavaScript pre-request script in Postman?

Tags: javascript, python, postman, iteration

I have an API endpoint that returns a maximum of 50 records per page. I need to extract data from subsequent pages and would normally write a loop in Python, but in this case the data provider has supplied a collection in Postman that runs a pre-request JavaScript script and creates a hash (for security/verification reasons). I am assuming that this pre-request needs to run for each iteration. The pre-request code that runs in Postman is supplied in the prerequest.js file

I have tried to convert this to Python but receive the message:

> *{"error":"Invalid signature","message":"The 'mac' value does not match
> the signature of the request. Ensure the 'mac' is calculated correctly
> using your secret and the request body is not being altered."}*

In summary, I have a pre-request in JavaSript in Postman; I have a Python template that would usually achieve the looping (with other data sources). I need help to iterate in Postman or by running a Python script outside of Postman.  All files referred to are available in my [Github repository](https://github.com/Moominman/crazy-code)